# Can I use a monitor with rs232c plug with my newer laptop?

Tags: display

Seems like a simple and frequently-asked question, but alas - answers all over the map, confusing, some say you can and some you can't.  Can I get a cable with rs232 to either usb or hdmi to connect older monitor to newer laptop??  Or will that not work?

Comment: You need to use a VGA connector for this, not USB or RS232.  There are HDMI to VGA converters to connect a VGA monitor to a newer computer

Comment: I think we need a photo of your old monitor's connector, because it's very unlikely to be "RS232" (that's a serial comms standard, not a connector)...

Answer (score 3):

I *highly* doubt you have a [RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) connector on your monitor.  I assume you are referring to a [VGA connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector), which looks like this:

[image: VGA connector]

Both are [D-sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature) styles of connectors, in which it is common for even knowledgeable people to mistake their type and purpose.

If you have a VGA connector, then there are multiple ways to connect your monitor to a computer. There are [DisplayPort to VGA adapters](https://www.google.com/search?q=displayport%20to%20vga%20adapter&oq=displayport%20to%20&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l7.5063j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or [HDMI to VGA adapters](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03wC_xWR9hhbJFIUGKfF9XSoA5R9Q%3A1584893118438&ei=vox3XtCwGpOEytMPpOy00Aw&q=HDMI%20to%20vga%20adapter&oq=HDMI%20to%20vga%20adapter&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67l2j0l8.30025.30660..31778...0.2..0.114.373.3j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30.UZxqleoXLy8&ved=0ahUKEwjQh9P6uq7oAhUTgnIEHSQ2DcoQ4dUDCAs&uact=5).  One of these would be the best choice. Simply choose the type that matches your laptop's display output.

There are also [USB to VGA adapters](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01fzllR-YxTIQdEct0XImQ2iW7m0w%3A1584893179097&ei=-4x3Xv7OBeGfytMPpIKJwAI&q=usb%20to%20vga%20adapter&oq=usb%20to%20vga%20adapter&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.2886.4087..4691...0.2..0.97.638.8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i273j0i20i263.T5Gf8Vy-bk0&ved=0ahUKEwi-uMmXu67oAhXhj3IEHSRBAigQ4dUDCAs&uact=5), as well.  I would avoid this option, unless you have no other choice.  Unless you have a USB3 port and purchased a USB3 adapter, the display will have a high latency.  Also, the adapter acts as its own display adapter, so you lose the power of your internal GPU.  These are fine for tasks like word processing, spreadsheets, etc.  However, they are not so good for gaming, video, or anything that requires fast screen updates.

On a side note, there were [computer terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) with serial port connectors.  However, that is a technology was mostly phased out 40+ years ago.

Comment: And the serial port in computer terminals wasn't used to transfer video information, so you can't plug one of those into a laptop (if the laptop had a serial port) and expect it to show the laptop screen.

Comment: @dirkt But you can connect them to a modern computer and use them as a terminal.  [TRS-80 DT-1 Refurb Pt2: Cleaning and Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgaCQdxR3r0&t=1s)

Comment: There _were_ also computer monitors with RGBI connections which AFAIK used the same DE-9 as serial ports... but those would be _very_ old.

Comment: @user1686 You are confusing *connectors* with *ports/interface*.  Connectors are physical and ports are protocol.  Connectors can connect *anything*.  Another example would be EGA.  EGA used a 9 pin D-sub connector, just like 9 pin serial, but it was not a serial interface.

Comment: @Keltari yes, I know. Been there, done that, but that needs setup on the computer (or Linux), and is not something the OP will expect...

Comment: @Keltari: That's exactly the point I was trying to make... I never said it was a serial interface.